# Spliting horizontal menu using nth-child?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to create a basic horizontal menu with a twist: position an image (logo) in the middle.  I have seen several examples on how to do so, using padding or negative margins, or transparent image placeholders and background images.  They were all too convoluded for my taste, and then I found an article on [Targeting Menu Elements using nth-child](http://css-tricks.com/targetting-menu-elements-submenus-navigation-bar/) and got my solution to work, almost!

The problem I am running into now is a spacing issue.  I have 3 menu items on the left, and 3 menu items on the right. My gut is telling me it's a simple math miscalculation but I have tried different paddings, alignments, margins, and positionings to no avail.

I need the following:

> [item] [item] [item] LOGO [item] [item] [item]

But I can't seem to get away from this:

> [item] [item] [item] LOG[item]O [item] [item]

I have achieved this using css and applying a margin equaling the width of the logo to the nth-child of the 3rd list item.  The problem is unless all menu items are exactly equal length, it seems to misalign the rest of the menu by a little.  I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<div id="branding">
    <h1 id="site-title">
        <a href="#"><img width="200" height="145" alt="Diamond Logo" src="http://cowgirlexpressions.com/working/_TESTING/menu-split-logo.jpg" class="header-image" /></a>
    </h1>
    <nav class="menu" id="menu-primary">
        <div class="wrap">
            <ul class="menu-items" id="menu-primary-items">
                <li><a href="#">Bio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Résumé</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Demos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
body { background-image: none; background-color: #000; } 


/* === Header & Site Title === */
#header {padding-top: 0;}
#branding {padding: 0; margin: 0; line-height:150px; height:150px; text-align: center; }
#site-title {line-height: 150px;}


nav.menu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; word-spacing: -4px; }
nav.menu li { display: inline-block; background-color: rgba(125, 125, 125, 0.3); }
nav.menu li a {
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 18px; 
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav.menu li a:hover { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3); }


/* === Main Menu === */
#branding nav#menu-primary {
    margin: -220px auto 0px auto;
    width: 940px; /*840px?*/ }
    #branding ul#menu-primary-items li { font-weight: bold; text-align: center; text-transform: uppercase; position: relative; }
        #branding ul#menu-primary-items li:nth-child(3) { margin: 0 0 0 0;  }
        #branding ul#menu-primary-items li:nth-child(4) { margin: 0 0 0 200px; }
        #branding ul#menu-primary-items li a { color: #809CAD; text-decoration: none; }
            #branding ul#menu-primary-items li a:hover { color: #BBAD9E; }
```

Changing the width on the **#branding nav#menu-primary** class seems to affect this, but I can't seem to get the right combo down.  Plus my content area has a max-width of 1200.  Do I need to set my menu container width to match? or to be 100%?  I could apply a padding to the whole menu by 20px and shift it over, but that doesn't seem like a clean solution, plus it puts the menu out of alignment above the rest of the page content. Should I be using margin/padding on the nth-child items or is there a better (CLEANER) way to do this?

See this **[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RodeoRamsey/2x7wo4gg/26/)** to get a better idea of my issue.  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: is the idea to have 3 menu items to the left of the logo and 3 to the right? like this: http://jsfiddle.net/2x7wo4gg/28/ ... now, when you resize the window, this will break because the header needs a fixed width for this to work... Am I on the right track?

Comment: @wf4, yes you're on the right track.  I believe my problem arises when the menu items are not all the exact same characters in length.  I don't mind if it breaks at smaller widths because I plan on using media queries to add responsive styles.

Comment: Also, that fiddle seems to be causing the whole menu nav to align-left while leaving the logo center-aligned, which throws things way out of whack.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that breaks but I just wanted to make sure I understood the problem before I tried to fix it :-)

Comment: Yes that 2nd fiddle looks good, let me see how it looks in other browsers and check some things! Thanks!

Comment: I deleted that second one because as you just commented, when the length of the text changes, it breaks again. :-( I did not know that the text was going to change. it was this http://jsfiddle.net/2x7wo4gg/30/

Comment: I think to do this "properly" in the way that you are doing it, you're going to need to use flexbox, which means not so great browser support...  So long as your link's have variables widths you are going to run into issues.  The only other alternative is to make sure each link is exactly the same width in all cases.

Comment: Additionally... The links are not lining up properly because your container is too small to support the links at their current size and also that margin...  When the last link breaks to a new line the links that fit on the first line center up in the total width available, this mis-aligning the links and the logo.  This process is fundamentally flawed. You quite simply are going to have issues like this at various sizes constantly.  You need to create something that relies on some known widths.

Comment: @Michael So how do you rely on known widths when you don't know the widths? While there will always be 3 on one side and 3 on the other, the exact text of the items might change slightly.

Comment: What I mean is to provide a percentage of width to all 6 LI's as well as a percentage width to the logo.  In this way ALL LI's have an equal width.  Depending on the text within, the space to the left and right of each links text (the internal padding) may vary.  It would then be up to you to define a font-size that allows all items to fit within that specified LI width.

Comment: Thank you @Michael - I am going to attempt this, although I did check out Flexbox and boy that looks shiny!!!

Comment: @RodeoRamsey - You will likely have better success this way as you are defining parameters that all items have to follow.